# Javascript and CSS specific files, how to include them by convention ? Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I include specific JS or CSS files (by convention ?) with Ruby Rails 3.1 ?

I have a view :
views/project/index.html.erb

And I want to include a specific javascript file for this page. I put it in
assets/javascripts/project/index.js

Same for another view :
home/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `application.css` and `application.js` file, be sure to remove the line `\\= require tree`.

Then, manually list all the css/js files you want included in each manifest file, for example:

```
// application.js
//= global.js
//= everywhere.js
```

Then, I would setup a yield in your header or your closing body tag for your application layout file, for instance (in haml)

```
%head
  %title Some Page
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
  = yield :stylesheets
```

Then in your particular view, say `_example_partial.html.haml`, do this:

```
- content_for :stylesheets do
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'example_partial'

-# the rest of your view goes here
```

You do the exact same thing with Javascript files, just using `javascript_include_tag` instead of `stylesheet_link_tag`.

This will let you quickly and easily assemble view-specific javascript / css payloads. There may be a more sophisticated way to handle this using the asset pipeline, but I would suggest that if the asset pipeline is already minifying and merging you major stylesheets that this kind of +1 css / js file per view is not going to cause a major performance hit. Just try to make sure you don't overdo it with dozens of separate files loading into a single view.

Comment: It's worth noting that this method works nicely in production. E.g. if you look at the source in production you'll see that the individual controller javascript file gets an appropriate cache-busting name, just like the main application.js file: <script src="/assets/mycontroller-923cef714b82e7dec46117f9aab7fb2c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: i think discovering whether a css or javascript file exist on the current view page would be better.